# C-x in terminal

Tags: key-bindings, term

In `M-x term`, how can I make `C-x` do what it does in line mode in char mode also? I know that `C-c` is one answer here but (a) that's not good enough for me and (b) I'm using emacs so there has to be a way. I don't ever use `C-x` in a terminal so that's not an issue.

Is there a key map for char mode terminal that I can modify to get what I want? I know there is a command to list key maps somewhere but I can't figure that out either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to re assign C-x as an escape character:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     ;; C-x is the prefix command, rather than C-c
     (term-set-escape-char ?\C-x)
     (define-key term-raw-map "\M-y" 'yank-pop)
     (define-key term-raw-map "\M-w" 'kill-ring-save)))
```

[from SO  - How to switch to a different buffer from a terminal buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348991/8544157)

Answer (score 0):

I have this hack in my init files to set both C-c and C-x as escape characters.  Normally, you can only have one.

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            ;; Hack to set two escape chars.
                            (let (term-escape-char)
                              (term-set-escape-char ?\C-x))
                            (let (term-escape-char)
                              (term-set-escape-char ?\C-c))))
```

This idea is taken from the code for `ansi-term` in `term.el`.

You can also just use `ansi-term` instead of `term` to start a terminal instead of using the above hack.